# Best way to parse large CSV files in ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

What is the best way to parse a large CSV file in ruby. My CSV file is almost 1 GB. I want to filter the data in CSV according to some conditions.

Comment: What's the way you're currently parsing it, and what's the specific problem with it? How would you measure "best"?

Comment: I tried smarter_csv and Rcsv gems. But it also taking long time.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] to explain the problem.

Comment: For Eg: I have a csv file containing record of students in a school with the mark they obtained. I have to write a ruby program to find the students with mark obtained above 70. The file size is 1 GB

Comment: How do you parse it **now** so that it’s too slow etc?

Comment: Ruby provides an excellent library CSV for working with, you guessed it csv files. I would investigate the foreach and filter and parse methods provided.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I tried to parse it  using smarter_csv and Rcsv gems.

Comment: Please don't ask us what's the best way, as that is determined by your environment. Are you going to import the data into a database? If so, DBMs have very efficient tools for importing CSV that are much faster than anything you could write in Ruby. Are you importing it into Excel? The same is true of Excel. I'd recommend showing what you tried and we can help improve it. I'd load the CSV into a database and work from there as a DBM is designed for this purpose.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't specifically say,  but I think most people commenting feel this is likely to be a homework question.  If so you should read "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)". If not read "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help)".

As G4143 stated in the comment Ruby has an excellent [CSV class](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) which should fit your needs.

Here are a couple of quick examples using `foreach` which the documentation describes as being intended as the primary method for reading CSV files. The method reads one line at a time from the file so it should work well with large files.  Here is a basic example of how you might filter out a subset of Csv records using it,  but I would encourage you to read the CSV class documentation and follow-up with more specific questions, showing what you have tried so far if you have trouble.

The basic idea is to start with an empty array, use `foreach` to get each row and if that row meets your filtering criteria, added to the initially empty filtered results array.

test.csv:

```
a, b, c
1,2,3


4,5,6
```

---

```
require 'csv'    

filtered = []
CSV.foreach("test.csv") do |row|
    filtered << row if row[0] == "1"
end
filtered
=> [["1", "2", "3"]]
```

---

In the case where the first line of the file is a "header" you can pass in an option to treat it as such:

```
require 'csv' 

filtered = []
CSV.foreach("test.csv", :headers => true) do |row|
    filtered << row if row["a"] == "1"
end
filtered
=> [#<CSV::Row "a":"1" " b":"2" " c":"3">]
```